# How can I move shape using OpenGl in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have create android application to draw mCircle and mTriangle using OpentGl:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Draw Triangle
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f); 
    mTriangle.draw(gl); // Draw triangle 

    //Draw Circle
    gl.glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -20.0f);
    mCircle.draw(gl);
}
```

My problem is when I try to move the mTriangle by:

```
   gl.glTranslatef(NewX, NewY, -10.0f);
```

then the mCircle is also moving!!.

My question, how can I move the mTriangle only(position of mCircle is fixed(0,0))? Or what is the command that can change position of the mTriangle at run time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformations are applied to current model matrix. Each new transformation is accumulated in this matrix. To keep initial transformation, OpenGL (<3) use Matrix Stack operations.

```
//For each model

    glPushMatrix() //save current matrix

    // Apply current model transformations 

    // Render model

    glPopMatrix() //restore matrix
```

So, in your code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

    //Draw Triangle
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(NewX, NewY, -10.0f);
    mTriangle.draw(gl); // Draw triangle 
    gl.glPopMatrix();


    //Draw Circle
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -20.0f);
    mCircle.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

}
```

Note that because your model matrix is Identity matrix, you could simply reload Identity between each model in place of push/pop matrix, which is used to handle more complex scene.

Comment: could you apply the glPushMatrix() and  glPopMatrix() in my code?